# python pandas-how to apply function according to another column's value

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a DataFrame like the image:

[image]

I need to add another column to DataFrame to calculate the "gram" for every product,according to diffierent Unit of the Number.
So,how to do ?

Comment: Can you post raw data (text not images), your code, your attempts, any errors and what the desired output looks like, at the moment you're asking us to do your coding for you, it's unclear for example if you have a problem with converting the imperial units to grams, performing the arithmetic calculations etc..

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Thanks guys! Seems @jezrael gives me  what I want.Sorry for not make this problem clearly. I tried Groupby or For loop, but None of them works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC if in column `UNIT` are only `lb` and `oz` use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['gram'] = np.where(df.UNIT == 'lb', df.number / 0.0022046, df.number / 0.035274)
```

Formulas:

[ounces-to-grams](http://www.metric-conversions.org/weight/ounces-to-grams.htm)
[pounds-to-grams](http://www.metric-conversions.org/weight/pounds-to-grams.htm)